# What errors can WebSocket emit?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Is there a list of all possible error events a js websocket client can emit? Are the errors spec'ed or are they implementation dependent?

```js
webSocket.on('error', (event) => ...) // What can event be?
```

Comment: I could not find any notes about that in the specification (totally misread your question, apologies)

Answer (score 1):

here is a list of Websocket errors codes that you might receive.
[websocket-close-codes](https://github.com/Luka967/websocket-close-codes)

Most likely you'll receive 1006 in case of an exception

Answer (score 1):

Browser-side error events are actually related to "close codes" used by the WebSocket protocol, [as detailed in section 11.7 to the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-11.7).

You can find the [registered WebSocket closure codes here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/websocket/websocket.xhtml#close-code-number).

In addition to server-side specified errors, some parsing errors and protocol errors are also emitted by the client (such as [UTF-8 requirements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-8))... which are often mapped to a closure code (UTF-8 is mapped to code 1003).

AFAIK, these closure error codes are actually sent to the `onclose` callback, as part of the `close` event. (i.e., `close_event.code`). However, [according to MDN when the closure isn't normal (code 1000), the `onerror` callback is **also** called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/error_event).

Personally I've never tested or coded anything with these error-codes, since they are **unreliable** and **optional**:

> When closing an established connection (e.g., when sending a Close frame, after the opening handshake has completed), an endpoint **MAY** indicate a reason for closure.

Exposing these "error codes" is **optional** for a reason. Sending error codes from a server to a client / application could (potentially) expose security vulnerabilities.